# Проверка, на каких прошивках запустится проект ios

Tags: ios, iphone

Скачал готовый проект [вот отсюда](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios), хотелось бы просто достроить проект на этом проекте, но не понимаю, как проверить, на каких версиях телефона будет работать приложение?
Имею в виду не версию телефона, а прошивку (8.1 , 7.0 и т.д.).

Comment: отсюда

http://tsya.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проект по ссылке собирался для 5.1. Будет ли он корректно работать на версиях выше проверяйте в симуляторе и на устройствах.

Comment: В симуляторе у меня sdk 8,1 - значит ли, что этот проект будет работать на телефоне 8,1? И если он работает в симуляторе, значит будет работать на реальном устройстве?

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов Это значит, что вы собираете проект с помощью sdk8,1, если собралось, то хорошо. В большинстве случаев если работает в симуляторе, то будет работать и на реальном устройстве.

Comment: @Zatoichy спасибо

Comment: Я бы сказал так, если работает в симуляторе определенной версии, то и на устройстве с такой же версией работать будет, но мелкие глюки не исключены. Впрочем, мелкие глюки в UI видел и между, скажем, iPhone и iPod, и уж тем более iPad, правда это давно было, еще во времена 6.х а то и раньше. Точно надо пробовать хотя бы на одном устройстве - есть отличия у симулятора и у девайса в целом, например, на OS X файловая система по умолчанию регистронезависима, а на iOS регистрозависима, в результате бывают казусы когда на симмуляторе у тебя все ОК, а на девайсе что-то просто не находится из ресурсов

Comment: Кстати, странный пример - -(void)loadContributors загрузка с сети в основном потоке

Comment: @aknew попробывал сейчас на устройстве, работает, вот только засада - всю сеть перерыл, а собранной версии парсера не нашёл (что бы и MainView и DetailView работали)